# Spring Boot Security Handling Errors In Resource Server when Authorization is not Available?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-authorization-server, spring-resource-server, oauth2resourceserver

I have configured the resource service in spring boot security to authorize request from separate authorization server. But when the server is unavailable I'm unable to catch the exception which is throwing when the server is not available (AuthenticationServiceException)

What are the ways to catch this exception?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class AuthIntrospector {


    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.introspection-uri}")
    private String introspectionUri;
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-id}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->
                        oauth2.opaqueToken(opaque -> opaque
                                        .introspector(opaqueTokenIntrospector()))
                )
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new IntrospectionEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpaqueTokenIntrospector opaqueTokenIntrospector() {
            return new SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector(introspectionUri, clientId, clientSecret);
    }
}
```

The exceptions that are throwing when the server is not available.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:8085/oauth2/introspect": Connection refused
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider.getOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider.java:132) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:10.1.15]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.OAuth2IntrospectionException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/introspect": Connection refused
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector.makeRequest(SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector.java:149) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector.introspect(SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider.getOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider.java:125) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/introspect": Connection refused
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:888) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:868) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:714) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector.makeRequest(SpringOpaqueTokenIntrospector.java:146) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:589) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:181) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:531) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:636) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:377) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1237) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1123) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:75) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.support.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.java:79) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:87) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:71) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:862) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

What are the ways that this exception can be catch?

Comment: Why would you catch such an exception? If the authorization server is down, introspection can't work and you actually have an internal server error (you won't be able to build the required `Authentication` instance...

Comment: @ch4mp I was getting unauthorized (401) error even the authorization server is unavailable. So if there is a possible way to catch the exception and return the appropriate response?